# Firefox freezing my whole desktop

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gnome

I'm using Firefox 7 on Ubuntu 11.10. I am not definitely sure that this problem began since upgrading Ubuntu from 11.04, but that would be my guess.

The problem is fairly simple. Firefox freezes at random times, and when it does, it freezes the whole desktop with it.

I have tried removing every single plug in I have, and the problem persisted. I tried installing them back in one by one to see if any was more problematic than the rest, but no plug in emerged as a clear candidate.

I have tried to discern a pattern. I thought the most likely culprit would be video, like when on YouTube, but that isn't it. Sometimes it happens when I haven't even gone to a web page yet, and I just click to open the bookmarks drop down from the menu.

I would try running `firefox -debug` from the command line, but the problem is once Firefox freezes, the desktop becomes completely inaccessible. I can still move the mouse, but I can't click on anything on the screen. I can't alt-tab between applications. All I can do is hit `ctrl+alt+backspace` and then log out.

Any help to diagnose this problem would be much appreciated. I don't mind using Chrome and Chromium (which are stable as rocks on my system), but I have some plug ins on Firefox I can't live without.

Comment: Hey, has someone a different solution? I don't like chrome due to lack of master password and tried a lot things including the VACUUM without much success. Via VACCUUM it got only a bit better but now it freezes several seconds especially on javascript intensive pages like twitter.

Comment: btw I have ubuntu 10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by Sqlite3 vacuuming delay. It's a cross-platform issue for recent Firefox versions.

http://jasonlefkowitz.net/2011/10/dear-mozilla-fix-your-damn-browser-already/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am experimenting with the SQLite3 VACUUM solution offered here: http://mozillalinks.org/2009/07/vacuum-your-firefox-databases-for-better-performance/ . Is there a command that I can use in Ubuntu that will allow me to run the SQLite Vacuum command on all SQLite files at once? places.sqlite is probably the main culprit, but I'd like to vacuum all of them anyway. I can't figure out how to do that in one command line, so I can only go one by one, like this: `sqlite3 places.sqlite VACUUM`

Comment: Yes, you can use find command: find . -name '*.sqlite' -exec sqlite3 {} VACUUM \;

Comment: Thank you. I have "vacuumed" all the sqlite files in my Firefox profile directory, and now I'm going to run Firefox for a day or so and see if it is any more stable. I'll report back here when and if it seems I have a clear result.

Comment: After running Firefox for a while, it seems that this solution has worked. I did experience one freeze, but unlike before, after waiting a few seconds, I got control back again. I assume I'll have to run this vacuum command every now and again until they fix this bug. Thank you for the help!